# Validate a 10 digit ISBN Number ERD Included

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make a program that check the ISBN number and sees if it has the correct check digit, if it doesn't have the check digit it will add one.  I have an Idea of how it will work I just cant figure out how to code for it as in the classes inheriting from each other.
This is an in class example that is not going to be graded it is just to familiarize us with getting our designs to a working program.  here's what I have so far mind you this is a simple console program.

[image]

**Code Updated**

```
public class isbn
{   //attributes
     private string isbnNum;
     //method   
     public string GetIsbn()
     {
         return this.isbnNum;
     }
       //constructor
       public isbn()
       {
           Console.Write("Enter Your ISBN Number: ");
           this.isbnNum = Console.ReadLine();

       }//end default constructor

        //method
       public string displayISBN()
       {

           return  this.GetIsbn();

       }


   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a new instance of the ISBN/book class

        isbn myFavoriteBook = new isbn();

        //contains the method for checking validity 
        bool isValid = CheckDigit.CheckIsbn(myFavoriteBook.GetIsbn());

        //print out the results of the validity.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your book {0} a valid ISBN",
                                   isValid ? "has" : "doesn't have"));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }//end main
```

This is the check digit code the professor provided in class we just have to mesh it up to get it to work. I know this goes in the check digit class what I don't know is how to incorporate it into code.

**Code Updated**

```
 public static class CheckDigit
{       // attributes
    public static string NormalizeIsbn(string isbn)
    {
        return isbn.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "");
    }
   public static bool CheckIsbn(string isbn) // formula to check ISBN's validity
    {
        if (isbn == null)
            return false;

        isbn = NormalizeIsbn (isbn);
        if (isbn.Length != 10)
            return false;

        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            if (!int.TryParse(isbn[i].ToString(), out result))
                return false;

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            sum += (i + 1) * int.Parse(isbn[i].ToString());

        int remainder = sum % 11;
        if (remainder == 10)
            return isbn[9] == 'X';
        else
            return isbn[9] == (char)('0' + remainder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the class `CheckDigit` is the business rules validator for ISBN numbers.

In that case:

```
public static class CheckDigit
{
    public static bool CheckIsbn(string isbn)
    { 
       //implementation as in your question.
    }
}
```

Now write a new application (here it's a console app) that uses both of your classes.

```
class MyConsoleApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a new instance of the ISBN/book class. you're prompted as part
        //of the constructor.
        isbn myFavoriteBook = new isbn();

        //new class contains the method for checking validity 
        bool isValid = CheckDigit.CheckIsbn(myFavoriteBook.GetIsbn());

        //write out the results of the validity.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your book {0} a valid ISBN", 
                                   isValid ? "has" : "doesn't have"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's what's happening:

- we create a new instance of isbn/book. Its constructor has the Console.Readline command to ask the user for input. It then stores the user's entry into `this.isbnNum`.
- our new static class `CheckDigit` is simply a validator of any given string. It determines whether the argument sent is a valid ISBN number. It'll return a bool. We sent it the `isbn.GetIsbn()`, which is what the user entered.
- the bool returned from the `CheckIsbn()` is displayed nicely in a sentence for the user in the console.

So really there are 2 main classes - `isbn` and the `CheckDigit`. The other `Main(string[] args)` can be removed from your code.

Here's the [entire console app in one file](http://pastebin.com/9VeGvshU). Paste into your application, and you can see what's happening.

Is that the help you were looking for? Either way, leave a comment, and we can get it sorted out for you.

**Updates:**

- The `CheckIsbn` really only does 1 thing - returns whether the 9th character is an X or some other number. It doesn't modify the ISBN from the user, as it stands today. If you wanted to maintain that formatting (removing dashes, spaces), and otherwise modify the input ISBN, then you could specify the ISBN as an `out` parameter.

Redefine your method like this if you want the ISBN entered by the user, to retain any changes made within the method `CheckIsbn`:

```
public static bool CheckIsbn(out string isbn)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand all of this yet can you explain it further like what exactly is happening in the classes after the user enter the isbn number.  like this class gets this info then passes it to the other one to do something. thanks

Comment: Basically the isbn class is the object that holds the isbn number (provided to the application somehow), hence the object name "myFavoriteBook", and "new isbn()" creating a new instance of that class.... After the class is created, we need to use the validator to see if the isbn is actually valid, hence, "CheckDigit.CheckIsbn" which calls a method within the CheckDigit class (separate class from the isbn), and passes the isbn as an argument and returns a bool representing whether or not it is valid....At this point, we simply write out the result to console... Does that help clear anything up?

Comment: Yes it does thank you guys I'm going to keep this open for a while so that I can ask more questions if I need too if that's alright. I'm going to code this tonight and see if I cant get it working, I might post some new code this evening if I start having trouble since I'm new to this .

Comment: how can I get it to generate the check digit if the user doesn't enter it?

Comment: @Michael: the only thing the user enters is their ISBN. The check is around whether it's actually a valid ISBN. The user doesn't enter a check digit with the code you've shown. As well, be aware the code currently supplied in `CheckIsbn()` doesn't compile - what is `r`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the code with the latest changes the check digit was supposed to create a digit if the characters were less than 10 digits. It would do this using the formula but maybe I did it wrong?
The code should compile now and any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Michael: updated my answer. It'd be up to you to code any changes if you wanted to create a digit in this code. Is the retaining of changes in the method what you were looking for?

Comment: @Michael, If you see something that looks as if it should be an ISBN but is only nine digits long, you probably don't have an ISBN sans checkdigit. You probably have an SBN. Convert it to an ISBN-10 by adding a leading zero, then check whether it's valid. (These will be seen only on pre-1974 British books.)