# Checking if an ISBN number is correct

Tags: python

I'm given some ISBN numbers e.g. `3-528-03851` (not valid) , `3-528-16419-0` (valid). I'm supposed to write a program which tests if the ISBN number is valid.

Here' my code:

```
def check(isbn):
    check_digit = int(isbn[-1])
    match = re.search(r'(\d)-(\d{3})-(\d{5})', isbn[:-1])

    if match:
        digits = match.group(1) + match.group(2) + match.group(3)
        result = 0

        for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
          result += (i + 1) * int(digit)

        return True if (result % 11) == check_digit else False

    return False
```

I've used a regular expression to check a) if the format is valid and b) extract the digits in the ISBN string. While it seems to work, being a Python beginner I'm eager to know how I could improve my code. Suggestions?

Comment: Looks good to me.  I like your use of slicing.  As the other person noted, your ternary expression can be simplified just by returning (result %11) == check_digit

Comment: You could also remove the blank likes, in accordance with PEP8 <http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/>

Comment: +1 for outstandingly working things out first and then still asking about improvement. Good job!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595217/validate-a-10-digit-isbn-number-erd-included, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696889/calculating-check-digit-for-isbn, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630701/isbn-generate-the-check-digit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, try to avoid code like this:

```
if Action():
    lots of code
    return True
return False
```

Flip it around, so the bulk of code isn't nested.  This gives us:

```
def check(isbn):
    check_digit = int(isbn[-1])
    match = re.search(r'(\d)-(\d{3})-(\d{5})', isbn[:-1])

    if not match:
        return False

    digits = match.group(1) + match.group(2) + match.group(3)
    result = 0

    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
      result += (i + 1) * int(digit)

    return True if (result % 11) == check_digit else False
```

There are some bugs in the code:

- If the check digit isn't an integer, this will raise ValueError instead of returning False: "0-123-12345-Q".
- If the check digit is 10 ("X"), this will raise ValueError instead of returning True.
- This assumes that the ISBN is always grouped as "1-123-12345-1".  That's not the case; ISBNs are grouped arbitrarily.  For example, the grouping "12-12345-12-1" is valid.  See http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/html/usm4.htm.
- This assumes the ISBN is grouped by hyphens.  Spaces are also valid.
- It doesn't check that there are no extra characters; '0-123-4567819' returns True, ignoring the extra 1 at the end.

So, let's simplify this.  First, remove all spaces and hyphens, and make sure the regex matches the whole line by bracing it in '^...$'.  That makes sure it rejects strings which are too long.

```
def check(isbn):
    isbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "");
    check_digit = int(isbn[-1])
    match = re.search(r'^(\d{9})$', isbn[:-1])
    if not match:
        return False

    digits = match.group(1)

    result = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
      result += (i + 1) * int(digit)

    return True if (result % 11) == check_digit else False
```

Next, let's fix the "X" check digit problem.  Match the check digit in the regex as well, so the entire string is validated by the regex, then convert the check digit correctly.

```
def check(isbn):
    isbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").upper();
    match = re.search(r'^(\d{9})(\d|X)$', isbn)
    if not match:
        return False

    digits = match.group(1)
    check_digit = 10 if match.group(2) == 'X' else int(match.group(2))

    result = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
      result += (i + 1) * int(digit)

    return True if (result % 11) == check_digit else False
```

Finally, using a generator expression and `max` is a more idiomatic way of doing the final calculation in Python, and the final conditional can be simplified.

```
def check(isbn):
    isbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").upper();
    match = re.search(r'^(\d{9})(\d|X)$', isbn)
    if not match:
        return False

    digits = match.group(1)
    check_digit = 10 if match.group(2) == 'X' else int(match.group(2))

    result = sum((i + 1) * int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(digits))
    return (result % 11) == check_digit
```

Comment: Nicely done. The only flaw I see is that consecutive hyphens or spaces are allowed, they should probably be flagged as an error.

Comment: "If the check digit is 11 ("X") : Do you mean 10? Also, you said you are using `max`, but I think you meant `sum`.  :::Hesitant to edit other people's posts without 100% certainty::: Also, there's another bug.  ISBN's are not grouped fully arbitrarily.  The link you pointed to states that there are always 4 groups.  Also, the 4th group is always 1 character in length.

Comment: @Brian: It's valid to not hyphenate at all, eg. when typing an ISBN off of a barcode.  There are also lots of other rules that you could validate if you wanted.  For example, the grouping isn't arbitrary.  Generally this doesn't matter when inputting an ISBN, though; you're really just checking for typos, and in any case it's beyond the scope of an intro-to-programming assignment.  It's worth noting, though.

Comment: Yes, I know.  My point was that it is *not* valid to have 4 or more hyphens.

Comment: @Brian: And my point is that there are *lots* of other validations that you could do.

Answer (score 4):

Pointless improvement: replace `return True if (result % 11) == check_digit else False` with `return (result % 11) == check_digit`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After 4 years of programming, I should know better. But then again, it's late, and I've run out of coffee :-).

Answer (score 3):

- The `check_digit` initialization can raise a `ValueError` if the last character isn't a decimal digit. Why not pull out the check digit with your regex instead of using slicing?
- Instead of search, you should probably use match, unless you want to allow arbitrary junk as the prefix. (Also, as a rule of thumb I'd anchor the end with `$`, though in your case that won't matter as your regex is fixed-width.)
- Instead of manually listing the groups, you could just use `''.join(match.groups())`, and pull the `check_digit` out afterwards. You might as well do the conversion to `int`s before pulling it out, as you want to convert all of them to `int`s anyway.
- your for loop could be replaced by a list/generator comprehension. Just use `sum()` to add up the elements.
- `True if (expression) else False` can generally be replaced with simply `expression`. Likewise, `False if (expression) else True` can always be replaced with simply `not expression`

Putting that all together:

```
def check(isbn):
    match = re.match(r'(\d)-(\d{3})-(\d{5})-(\d)$', isbn)
    if match:
        digits = [int(x) for x in ''.join(match.groups())]
        check_digit = digits.pop()
        return check_digit == sum([(i + 1) * digit
                                  for i, digit in enumerate(digits)]) % 11
    return False
```

The last line is arguably unnecessary, as the default behavior would be to return None (which is falsy), but explicit returns from some paths and not from others looks like a bug to me, so I think it's more readable to leave it in.

Answer (score 2):

*All that regex stuff is great if you belong to the isbn.org compliance inspectorate.*

However, if you want to know if what the potential customers type into their browser is worth pushing into a query of your database of books for sale, you don't want all that nice red uniform caper. Simply throw away everything but 0-9 and X ... oh yeah nobody uses the shift key so we'd better allow x as well. Then if it's length 10 and passes the check-digit test, it's worth doing the query.

From http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/html/usm4.htm

> The check digit is the last digit of
>   an ISBN. It is calculated on a modulus
>   11 with weights 10-2, using X in lieu
>   of 10 where ten would occur as a check
>   digit.
>
> This means that each of the first nine
>   digits of the ISBN -- excluding the
>   check digit itself -- is multiplied by
>   a number ranging from 10 to 2 and that
>   the resulting sum of the products,
>   plus the check digit, must be
>   divisible by 11 without a remainder.

which is a very long-winded way of saying "each of all the digits is multiplied by a number ranging from 10 to 1 and that the resulting sum of the products must be divisible by 11 without a remainder"

```
def isbn10_ok(s):
    data = [c for c in s if c in '0123456789Xx']
    if len(data) != 10: return False
    if data[-1] in 'Xx': data[-1] = 10
    try:
        return not sum((10 - i) * int(x) for i, x in enumerate(data)) % 11
    except ValueError:
        # rare case: 'X' or 'x' in first 9 "digits"
        return False


tests = """\
    3-528-03851
    3-528-16419-0
    ISBN 0-8436-1072-7
    0864425244
    1864425244
    0864X25244
    1 904310 16 8
    0-473-07480-x
    0-473-07480-X
    0-473-07480-9
    0-473-07480-0
    123456789
    12345678901
    1234567890
    0000000000
    """.splitlines()

for test in tests:
    test = test.strip()
    print repr(test), isbn10_ok(test)
```

Output:

```
'3-528-03851' False
'3-528-16419-0' True
'ISBN 0-8436-1072-7' True
'0864425244' True
'1864425244' False
'0864X25244' False
'1 904310 16 8' True
'0-473-07480-x' True
'0-473-07480-X' True
'0-473-07480-9' False
'0-473-07480-0' False
'123456789' False
'12345678901' False
'1234567890' False
'0000000000' True
'' False
```

Aside: a large well-known bookselling site will accept 047307480x, 047307480X, and 0-473-07480-X but not 0-473-07480-x `:-O`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nice -- well done for writing idiomatic Python! Here are some minor things:

---

When you see the idiom

```
result = <initiator>
for elt in <iterable>:
    result += elt
```

you can replace it by a list comprehension. In this case:

```
result = sum((i+1)*int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(digits)
```

or even more concisely:

```
return sum((i+1)*int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(digits) % 11 == check_digit
```

Of course, it is a value judgement whether this is better than the original. I would personally consider the second of these to be best.

Also, the extra parentheses in `(result % 11) == check_digit` are extraneous and I don't really think you need them for clarity. That leaves you overall with:

```
def validate(isbn):
    check_digit = int(isbn[-1])
    match = re.search(r'(\d)-(\d{3})-(\d{5})', isbn[:-1])

    if match:
        digits = match.group(1) + match.group(2) + match.group(3)
        parity = sum((i+1)*int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(digits)
        return parity % 11 == check_digit
    else:
        return False
```

Note that you do still need the `return False` to catch the case that the ISBN is not even in the right format.

Comment: Which type of exception could I raise if the format of the string does not match?

Comment: Not sure an exception is the way to go here; when writing a `validate` method it is not exceptional to have an invalid argument.

Comment: I think some of your calls to `sum` are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Omg your are 19y old! I wish I'd program that well at this age!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget (though this may be outside of the scope of your assignment) to calculate the check digit of the ISBN (the final digit), to determine if the ISBN is *valid* and not just *seemingly valid*.

There's some information about the implementation of the check digit [on the ISBN.org website](http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/html/usm4.htm), and implementation should be fairly straightforward.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) offers one such example (presuming you've already converted any ASCII "X" to a decimal 10):

```
bool is_isbn_valid(char digits[10]) {
    int i, a = 0, b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a += digits[i];  // Assumed already converted from ASCII to 0..10
        b += a;
    }
    return b % 11 == 0;
}
```

Applying this for your assignment is left, well, as an exercise for you.

Comment: If you do look up any more info on check digits, just be sure to look up ISBN-10, not ISBN-13, as the check digit methods do differ (naturally).  Alternatively, be even more impressive with your assignment, and handle both cases automatically and return if it's valid ISBN-10, ISBN-13 or invalid!

Comment: Nice idea, I probably do that ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Your check digit can take on the values 0-10, based on the fact that it's modulo-11. There's a problem with the line:

```
    check_digit = int(isbn[-1])
```

as this works only for the digits 0-9. You'll need something for the case when the digit is 'X', and also for the error condition when it isn't any of the above - otherwise your program will crash.