# Which exception to raise if a given string does not match some format?

Tags: python, exception

This is a follow up to an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047511/checking-if-an-isbn-number-is-correct).

Given a ISBN number, e.g. `3-528-03851-5` which exception type should I raise if the passed in string doesn't match the format X-XXX-XXXXX-X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raise a `ValueError`.

It's pretty much the standard way of saying "you've given me a value that doesn't make sense". For example:

```
>>> int("a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
>>> import shlex; shlex.split("'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Contrast this with a `TypeError`, which is raised when a type is incorrect:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[{}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd make an exception class to raise in this instance since its a very specific type of exception. You can extend the ValueError class pretty easily:

```
class ISBNFormatException(ValueError):
    """Raised when an invalid ISBN format is found"""
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

The ValueError might be the most appropriate choice.  According to its docs, it's when a value has the correct type but an inappropriate value.

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError