# ValueError: No closing quotation

Tags: python

I have the following code which returns the public IP's

```
def gather_public_ip():
    ACCESS_KEY = config.get('aws','access_key')
    SECRET_KEY = config.get('aws','secret_key')
    regions = regions = ['us-west-2','eu-central-1','ap-southeast-1']
#    regions = config.get('aws','region').split(',')
    all_EIP = []
    for region in regions:
       client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
       addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
       for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
         if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
            print eip_dict['PublicIp']
#       return str(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
            all_EIP.append(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
       print all_EIP
#           print str(all_EIP)
       return str(all_EIP)
```

This is called and returned as :

```
   net_range = gather_public_ip()
   for ip in net_range:
          r = s.run(ip)
```

run looks like :

```
def run(self, targets="" ,options="-Pn"):
    #start a new nmap scan on localhost with some specific options

    syslog.syslog("Scan started")
    parsed = None
    nmproc = NmapProcess(targets,options)
    rc = nmproc.run()

    if rc != 0:
        syslog.syslog("nmap scan failed: {0}".format(nmproc.stderr))
    try:
        parsed = NmapParser.parse(nmproc.stdout)
        self.report = parsed
    except NmapParserException as e:
        syslog.syslog("Exception raised while parsing scan: {0}".format(e.msg))

    syslog.syslog("Scan complete")
    syslog.syslog("Scan duration: "+ str(parsed.elapsed))
    self.report = parsed
    return parsed
```

after printing the list , this throws me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portwatch.py", line 300, in <module>
    r = s.run(ip)
  File "portwatch.py", line 239, in run
    rc = nmproc.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libnmap/process.py", line 257, in run
    else shlex.split(self.__nmap_command_line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Comment: What is `s` you call `.run(ip)` on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `ip` is not `""` or shlex will fail, cf [Which exception to raise if a given string does not match some format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047752/which-exception-to-raise-if-a-given-string-does-not-match-some-format)