# Why is my code outputting 0000000000000 as an invalid ISBN number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

0000000000000 is a valid ISBN number, but my code says it's invalid.
My code takes a 13-digit number and checks if it's valid or not.

Each of the first 12 digits of the ISBN is alternately multiplied by 1 and 3. Then, we sum them up and divide the sum by 10, and get the reminder. If 10 minus the reminder is equal to the 13th digit, then it's valid.

```
isbnNunmberCheck=input()

n1=int(isbnNunmberCheck[0])*1
n2=int(isbnNunmberCheck[1])*3
n3=int(isbnNunmberCheck[2])*1
n4=int(isbnNunmberCheck[3])*3
n5=int(isbnNunmberCheck[4])*1
n6=int(isbnNunmberCheck[5])*3
n7=int(isbnNunmberCheck[6])*1
n8=int(isbnNunmberCheck[7])*3
n9=int(isbnNunmberCheck[8])*1
n10=int(isbnNunmberCheck[9])*3
n11=int(isbnNunmberCheck[10])*1
n12=int(isbnNunmberCheck[11])*3

k=10-(n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10+n11+n12)%10

if k==int(isbnNunmberCheck[-1]):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: 10 - 0 != 0... are you sure its valid?

Comment: `0 % 10` is `0`, `10 - 0` is `10`, `10` is not `0`.

Comment: if you have 100 numbers, will you create 100 variables?

Comment: 0000000000000 is a valid ISBN number, its the only one exception. According to the ISBN Users' Manual, “Each of the first 12 digits of the ISBN is alternately multiplied by 1 and 3. The check digit is
equal to 10 minus the remainder resulting from dividing the sum of the weighted products of the
first 12 digits by 10 with one exception. If this calculation results in an apparent check digit of
10, the check digit is 0.”

Comment: If it's an exception and you haven't handled the exception, why did you think it would work?

Comment: if isbn==0000000000000:
    print("Valid")
is not working

Comment: it's not the only exception. Remainder 0 means that 10-<remainder> = 10, which cannot be equal to any digit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Checking if an ISBN number is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047511/1324033)

Comment: @DeepSpace: The parenthesis did make a difference. At least the number is now valid ;) The OP must look more into it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how do I simplify it with a for loop? for i range (1,12):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key statement is:

`If this calculation results in an apparent check digit of 10, the check digit is 0`

from your comment NOT your original question.

So if the check digit comes out to be 10 you actually need to use 0 in your comparison.

Calculate your check number then:

```
k = 0 if k == 10 else k
```

Comment: Or just do `if k % 10 == int(isbnNunmberCheck[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Well, your sum is 0, so the remainder will be 0, then (10 - the remainder) = 10, so 10 != 0.

I think looking [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10_check_digit_calculation), your alogrithm is incorrect to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> If 10 minus the remainder is equal to the 13th digit, then it's valid.

For your ISBN, "10 minus the remainder" is `10 - 0 % 10 = 10`. This is not equal to the 13th digit, which is `0`. Since `10 != 0`, the ISBN is invalid.

But your code is verbose. Let's consider a better way of writing your algorithm:

```
isbn_str = input()

k = 10 - (sum(map(int, isbn_str[0:-1:2])) + sum(map(int, isbn_str[1:-1:2]))*3) % 10

print(k)

if k == int(isbn_str[-1]):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Notice you can slice strings in the same way you can slice lists, i.e. with the syntax `start:stop:step`. `map` + `int` converts each element of an iterable to an integer lazily and `sum` takes those integers and sums them. See also [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: Care to explain your "better way"?

Comment: @Bazingaa, Yes, see my explanation below the code.

Comment: That still outputs `0000000000000` as `Invalid`

Comment: @DeepSpace, Yes, because it is :)

Comment: Minor grievance, but it's ISBN not ISIN :).  Note given the original piece of code I doubt OP has all the fundamentals to understand what's going on here though.

Comment: @jpg It is **valid**, according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-13_check_digit_calculation If `r` (`k` in this case) is 10 then the check digit (the 13th) should be `0`.

Comment: @DeepSpace, But not according to OP's algorithm. I can't (or am not willing to) fit their logic with reality, but I'm happy to improve existing logic.

Comment: @jpp Fair enough, but I think your answer should at least point out that OP's algorithm is wrong

Comment: @DeepSpace, *But it's right*... according to their logic "Each of the first 12 digits of the ISBN is alternately multiplied by 1 and 3... If 10 minus the reminder is equal to the 13th digit, then it's valid." I see what you are saying. But I don't know the ISBN rules and IMO are outside SO scope *unless defined in the question*.